# Express.js res.render not redirecting, just displayed in console

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

This time I want to use `res.render` to display html as success of DB update. I did it several times, but this time it doesn't work. It's not render html file, just displayed on chrome's console.

I think it caused because of async problem or duplicated response. I tried to many ways but I couldn't solve it, so pointers appreciated.

The code is related when the user paid service, increase user's level.

**Get Access Token => Validate => res.render**

```
app.post('/payment/validate', function(req, res, next){

// Get access token 
request.post({
    url : 'https://payment-company/get/token'
}, function(err, response, body) {
    if(!err & response.statusCode == 200) {
        var result = JSON.parse(body);
        var accessToken = result.response.access_token;

    // Validate payment (compare paid and would be paid)
        request.get({
            headers : { 'Authorization' : accessToken }
            url : 'https://payment-company/find/paymentid'
        }, function (err, response, body) {

            if (!err && response.statusCode == 200){
                var result = JSON.parse(body);

                if (result.response.amount == req.body.price){
                    Members.findOne({id : req.user.id}, function(err, member){

                        // If no problem, update user level
                        member.level = 2;
                        member.save(function(err, result){
                            if (err) return next();

                            res.render('payment.view.result.ejs',
                                {
                                    title : 'Success !',
                                    description : 'level up.'
                                });
                        });
                    });
                } 
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }); 
    }
})
});
```

sorry to verbose code I tried to shorten code, No problem until res.render, res.render will work but it's not display page instead it just send html code to chrome's console.

Comment: FWIW you don't need to add the `.ejs` when passing a view name to `res.render()`.

Comment: @mscdex I did it because file name has dots, Thanks.

Comment: "it just send html code to chrome's console" sounds like the problem is on the frontend not the backend... Is this an AJAX request?

Comment: @swider Yes. It is ajax request, It was `success: function(data){ console.log(data) }`, sorry the mistake, but even I delete `success callback` the problem is same. not rendered html, I think it maybe it just function's response, not a whole page. I saved fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bexoss/mfdL9z4y/ .

Comment: I give up, and I choose don't render, just sendStatus(200) and then redirect in frontend. so... the question has some misunderstanding, sorry to it... If you want to see frontend code please see the fiddle, thanks for your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a bit of a misunderstanding of how these requests work. What I think you intend:

1. Browser makes a GET request, server responds with an HTML document, the browser renders it
2. User takes an action
3. Browser makes a POST request, server responds with an HTML document, the browser renders it

What you've started coded on the frontend is an alternate method:

3. You make a POST request via AJAX, server responds with some JSON, you modify the current document with JavaScript to let the user know

Comment: yes the ajax request won't render so I just send it by form post. It worked for me. Thanks.