# My page is not rendering when calling URL from AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

I have made a route which is called in a specific event(click event) through AJAX.
My route is called but the page is not rendered with the call.

My AJAX function:

```
function showProfile(user_id) {
console.log("show pro:" + user_id);
$.ajax({
    url: "/users/profile?id=" + user_id,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

}

My route:

```
router.get('/profile',middleware.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
console.log(req.query.id);
res.render('profile');
```

});

My code through which I am making the AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/users/friendSearch/" + q,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("here");
            //data = JSON.parse(data);
            var output = "";
            data.forEach(function (t) {
                output += '<div class="card three wide column" ' +
                    'onclick=showProfile(' + t.oAuth_id + ')>' +
                    '<div class="image">' +
                    '<img src="/assets/matthew.png">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="content">' +
                    '<div class="header">' + t.firstName + " " + t.lastName + '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="extra content">' +
                    '<div class="ui button" onclick=addFriend('+t.oAuth_id+') ' +
                    'id="follow">' +
                    'Follow' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
            });
            document.getElementById("user_placeholder").innerHTML = output;

        }
    });
```

I am dynamically creating the HTML code and have added an onclick method in the div

I am able to print the id which I am sending through the AJAX call but my EJS page is not loading 
Thanks

UPDATE: 
I am getting a 304 on response

Comment: I believe your code does get the data from the NodeJS back-end. And I assume your problem is that you want to render the data to your page after successful request. In that case, you probably should have a `<div>` to contain that data. But before that, do you mind including your HTML EJS code?

Comment: Just did that
Please have a look

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but do you mind sharing the content of `data` which your `showProfile()` receives upon successful request? The 304 response is possibly caused by the response data being the same.

Comment: I am sending the id in the showProfile() function.The id which was received in the function is :
552515916436987050000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is a problem with invoking a `res.render()` route via AJAX since it simply returns the HTML string (as you probably see in your Response Preview in your Developer Tools -> Network -> Response Preview), and not do anything else. So, I would suggest using something like this in concept:

```
function showProfile(user_id) {
    console.log("show pro:" + user_id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/users/profile?id=" + user_id,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("userprofile").innerHTML = data
        }
    });
}
```

...in order to render the HTML data that the `/profile` route responded with, into

```
<div id="userprofile"></div>
```

Or, you can take a different approach by using `res.json()` to return data instead and manually outputting it to the HTML.

Answer to similar problem to yours: [Express.js res.render not redirecting, just displayed in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261360/express-js-res-render-not-redirecting-just-displayed-in-console)

Comment: But the URL won't change if I just render the data which the route had provided. 
I want the URL to change as well. What if I use POST method ?

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. But using POST via AJAX again will not make any change since its still only returning the HTML from the `res.render()`. If you want the URL to change, then using redirect or href is the answer, e.g.: `document.location.href='/users/profile?id=' + user_id` or `window.location='/users/profile?id=' + user_id`, or open a new tab/page for it. Also please see the post I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nifty answer:

```
<p onclick="your_function(event.target)">
<!-- Your stuff here -->
</p>
```

it should be very easy to implement whatever links you have in there to your code.